# Are controllers always awake?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I guess awake isn't the right word. Say I have a multi-page, large AngularJs application. Is the controller of a page that isn't active right now awake? For example, if I wanted to call a function of that controller with $rootScope.$broadcast, would it be listening for that signal or would it only recieve that signal when I go to the part of the page that requires that controller? Sorry if this makes not much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers have instances per usage, that means that angularJS will make an instance of some controller only if it is **in use**.

If you need to pass data from one controller to other, the common way is to use some service. As service are singletons which created on the first inject.

So, you can inject a service in one controller (page), invoke some method on it, which will change some data on it, then navigate to other page, in this page, inject the service, and use the data on it.

Comment: I understand that `$rootScope.$broadcast` isn't working because the instance of the controller isn't created, therefore it can't listen to the event. Are you recommending that I convert the function I need into a service, or inject a service into both controllers that can call that function for me? That part I didn't understand exactly.

Comment: Also, when the controller instance is eventually created, will the event still be caught by the `$scope.$on` in the controller or does the event need to be caught exactly when it is propagated, or it is lost? I'm guessing the latter? Thanks very much.

Comment: You wanted to use broadcast to send data to some controller, instead, use service, which will "hold" the data on it, and this way the second controller will get it.

As of the second question, angularjs's broadcast doesn't supports persist events.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to send data, just call a function in the controller from another controller. Previous stack answers recommended broadcast, but I guess it doesn't work in my case because its not listening for the event. Thanks, I will look into converting the functions I need into a service.

Comment: If you can explain the use case, maybe there is a better approach :]

Comment: Basically, in a controller there are some API functions, and in a seperate directive in a seperate page i need some functions from that API. Its not written as a service though, because its usage was specific to one area previously but I need to expand its usage area into one more directive. I tried $rootScope.$broadcast, but the event isn't triggering with $scope.$on. I figured it was because it wasn't listening for the event, and I guess you confirmed because it wasn't instantiated. Is a service still the best approach in this case, if I have explained sufficiently?